# Dynamic RadioButtons

Tags: apache-flex

Our resident Flex expert is out for the day and I thought this would be a good chance to test this site out. I have a dropdown with a dataProvider that is working fine:

```
<ep:ComboBox id="dead_reason" selectedValue="{_data.dead_reason}"
    dataProvider="{_data.staticData.dead_reason}"
    labelField="@label" width="300"/>
```

The ComboBox is custom but I'm not sure if that matters for the question. I need to change the combo box to radios (all in one group) but maintain the dynamic options. In other words, what is the best way to generate dynamic RadioButtons?

Answer (score 3):

Try using an <mx:Repeater>  Something like:

```
<mx:Repeater dataProvider="{_data.staticData.dead_reason}">
   <mx:RadioButton groupName="reasons" ...>
</mx:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:RadioButtonGroup id="RDO_Group"/>
<mx:Repeater id="myRepeater" dataProvider="{_data.staticData.dead_reason}">
<mx:RadioButton id="rdo" label="{myRepeater.currentItem}" value="{myRepeater.currentItem}" groupName="RDO_Group"/>
</mx:Repeater>
```

is the best way.